# react-hook-form: handleSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to use `react-hook-form` to handle input from the user. React gives me an error saying "handleSubmit is not a function". Any help would be appreciated.

My code is as followed (**react-hook-form 7.13.0**)

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Style = styled.div`
    .form {
        width: 200px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
`;

const Add = (props) => {
    const { register , handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (e, data) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(data);
        addReview(data);
    }

    const addReview = (data) => {
        axios.POST("http://localhost:3000/reviews", data).then(() => {
            props.setReviews([...props.reviews, {data}])
        })
    }
    return (
        <Style>
            <h3>Add a review</h3>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Book Title" ref={register}></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Rating" ref={register}></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Review" ref={register}></input>
                <input type="submit" placeholder="Review"></input>
             </form>
        </Style>
    )
};

export default Add;
```

Comment: You need either `handleSubmit` passed in props, or local function `onSumbit = (e, data)`. `onSubmit` on `<form onSubmit={FUNCTION} >` require a function, you MUST NOT call it there, React will call it for you, passing event and other parameters. It shoud be like `onSubmit={onSubmit}` or `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` if you passed it as a props. If not, you'll get error saying `handleSubmit` is not a function.

Comment: And also, if you're still calling, then make sure that `handleSubmit(onSubmit)` returns  a function.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, you get it from `useForm()`. Try to log it in console, or dive into package codes to see if the name is still the same.

Comment: Have you tried to register fields? Like : `<input type="text" placeholder="Book Title" {...register('title')} />` OR `<input type="text" placeholder="Book Title" {...register('title', { required: true })} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass this for every `input` with the `name` in order to register:

```
{...register("rating")}
```

Reference: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this...

```
const Add = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    addReview(data);
  };

  const addReview = (data) => {
    axios.POST("http://localhost:3000/reviews", data).then(() => {
      props.setReviews([...props.reviews, { data }]);
    });
  };
  return (
    <Style>
      <h3>Add a review</h3>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Book Title"
          {...register("bookTitle")}
        ></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rating" {...register("rating")}></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Review" {...register("review")}></input>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Review"></input>
      </form>
    </Style>
  );
};
```

Comment: Good Answer. But you need to capture OP's attention on the part that would solve the issue, like @MajedBadawi did in his accepted answer. This way, OP can directly find your point.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo.

This is what you have currently:

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

You call `handleSubmit(onSubmit)` but I'm guessing you are trying to use `onSubmit` as a handler. Replace the line above with this:

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

Comment: I believe the OP is using `useForm` from https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform, where `handleSubmit` is supposed to return a function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I thought this was the case originally, however, all tutorials I look at pass the onSubmit as an argument to handleSubmit. Check this link out https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

Comment: Try to console.log `useForm()` to see if it has function `handleSubmit`. The name may have been changed

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks I didn't realize that.

Comment: @GDelseaux I think you have compatibility issue. This old `7.0.0` codes contains `handleSubmit` and `watch` while the new one does not contain them: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/v7.0.0/src/useForm.ts

Comment: The formControls for `v7.13.0` are created here, and it has `handleSubmit` defined as a function. That's weird: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/v7.13.0/src/logic/createFormControl.ts

Answer (score -1):

[You have to register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lamarr-gyguv?file=/src/Add.js)

Like this `<input type="text" placeholder="Rating" {...register("Rating")}></input>`

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here as possible (i.e. the code), at least the minimum needed to actually accomplish what you are suggesting, and use links only for reference. Posts on Stack Overflow (and all of Stack Exchange) must be self-contained. Enough information needs to be in your answer such that the reader doesn't *need to* go to another page and/or off-site for the actual answer. Right now, users would *almost* need to go to the link you provided to get the answer.